# I have a database with a table containing a column of type BLOB

Tags: blob, blobstorage

When i select the column called data i am returned the following:

Does anyone know what this is?  How can i interpret this?

```
btf64e8yw4M7sYCcSyEnYYd/Ca13SyjB1+3x7i0kIb/vAsH793o9wXEGu81/oNwoFx+o7HixW8UMd6rIFM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```

Comment: This is a **B**inary **L**arge **Ob**ject. It is data that is meant to be interpreted as 1s and 0s -- which can mean anything and depends on the context. Your database engine is interpreting it with a character encoding, such as UTF-8, but it's still just binary.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not create the database but was hoping to be able to edit some of the information in it.  This field seems to be where the data is kept.  I guess the only way to figure it out is to get help from the original author regarding this field?

Comment: Absolutely. For all we know, this data could be an image, an executable, an excel file... Unless you have some other contextual clues, it's impossible to know the intent of this field.

Answer (score 0):

I would try dumping the contents of a couple of the fields to files and examine them to determine how the data is being stored. If you're using MySQL Workbench, there's an option to save the file when you right click on it.

If you save it without an extension and you're lucky, the operating system will recognize the file and may display an image thumbnail or be able to open the file for you. I dumped a png file as 'file' and my OS displayed a thumbnail of the image.

If that doesn't work, I'd open the file using an octal dump program. In linux, you can use the `od` command. For Windows, you can download [xd](http://www.fourmilab.ch/xd/). In Linux, I'd run `od -c > file_dump.txt` and then look at the contents. Depending on the encoding of the data, the contents of file_dump.txt may or may not be helpful. For example, the characters at the beginning of the file may tell you the file type, such as PNG.